# What species does this tooth belong to and how old could it be?

Tags: species-identification, fossil

As far as I can tell, this is a single rooted tooth. I suspect (or hope because it would be very cool) it being pretty old, since it is so dark in colour. It is not very pointy, so it doesn´t look like a carnivore tooth to me.

On the picture I think the sequence of the the positional relationship from front left to bottom right is labial, palatinal, mesial, distal.
I'm leaning towards a mandibular incisor. I'm not sure if this could be a human tooth, but it fits size-wise.

It was found on a glacial freshwater lake in Germany. The right side of the scale is in cm.

I would be grateful if anyone has an idea about the owner of this tooth, or could point me in a good direction on how to further narrow it down.

[image]

Comment: there's a reddit called what's this bone.

Comment: Tooth is a good guess, but it's not a human tooth, that much is certain. The root is curved, which would imply (if it's a mandibular tooth) that the mandible is shorter and more curved than ours. My goats had teeth that looked similar to this, but that's not much help, sorry.